# Fullscreen Interactive mode in Flash 11.4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to use Fullscreen interactive mode in a Flash application embedded inside HTML, using Flash Player 11.4, so I can access the keyboard events in fullscreen. It works fine, but I do have an issue: even after dismissing the "allow" dialog, whenever I touch any of the borders of the screen, the overlay pops up again, and stays there for several seconds, which is very annoying, especially since I (probably?) have no reliable way to tell that it's happening and it's covering parts of the game's UI.

Is there any way to suppress this behaviour? I can't even find it mentioned in any of the documentation!